# How sequencing works when we add Identity column for an existing table

Tags: sql-server, sequence, identity, auto-increment, alter-table

I have an existing table with no primary key but has a clustered index on createdate column. I need to add an identity column
If I alter the table to add an new column and set it identity then how the sequencing happens in SQl server.
I want the Id =1 to be set for the first row of the table based on createdate ascending

Answer (score 1):

If you care about the assignment order you must insert into a new table and then switch them.

On an `INSERT ... SELECT ... ORDER BY` Identity values are guaranteed to be generated in the order specified by the ORDER BY query.

Use SSMS's table designer to add the column and then generate the change script.  It should script out the full create,load,drop,rename transaction for you, and you just need to add the ORDER BY on the query that loads the new table.